# GCP Deployment - Module not found: Can't resolve '@public/badge/badge-xxl-execellent.png', for png/svg file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, import, nextjs-image

everyone! Can someone help me with this, I've been stuck with this error since morning, couldn't understand what is happening. I'm deploying my next js application through gcp cloud build and Firebase, and for some reason, build fails and logs the error like this for images like png/svg -

`Module not found: Can't resolve '@public/badge/badge-xxl-execellent.png'`

[GCP Cloud Build History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bzrc.png)
[GCP Logs Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kASQb.png)

Even though I have all these images inside my public folder and all works fine in local server. This error comes while deployment which makes the deployment fails.

The log message also states - Build failed because of webpack errors; Error ID: 1a2262f3, and I don't have such webpack configuration in my project.

Here is my `next.config.js` file -

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: false,
    distDir: ".next",
    images: {
        domains: [
            "storage.googleapis.com",
            "firebasestorage.googleapis.com",
            "crunchbase-production-res.cloudinary.com",
            "lh3.googleusercontent.com",
        ],
    },
};
```

That's the `tsconfig.json` -

[tsconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXevD.png)

I'm using the latest next.js and react.js version -

```
"next": "^13.1.2",    
"react": "^18.2.0",   
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",    
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.1",


// dev dependencies
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "16.11.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.20.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.1.2"
},
```

Please can someone help me on this and make me understand why it is happening?

I've assigned alias in tsconfig file. Importing and using my png/svg like this -

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Logo from '@public/navbar/navbarIcon.svg';
import futuristic_beautiful from "@public/about/futuristic_beautiful.png";

// With next js Image tag
<Image src={Logo} width={45} height={45} alt="Logo" />
<Image src={futuristic_beautiful} width={120} height={120} alt="" />

// With normal HTML img tag
<img src={Logo.src} width={45} height={45} alt="Logo" />
<img src={futuristic_beautiful.src} width={120} height={120} alt="" />
```

For errors related to svg images, I tried `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack` this on next.config.js file but no luck, then I replaced/comment out my all svgs import and directly passes the string path '/badge/badge-xxl-execellent.svg' like this in next js Image tag, so then it doesn't provide the error.

Webpack configuration was like this, but I removed that also when didn't worked-

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
}
```

and svg then imported like this -

```
import Logo from '@public/navbar/navbarIcon.svg';
<img src={Logo} alt="logo" />
<Logo />
```

Also, in global.d.ts file I declare this statement too -

```
declare module "*.module.css";
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.jpg";
declare module "*.svg";
```

But then it start showing errors for png files too & I couldn't understand why it is happening. Then I updated my next js from version 12 to 13 also react to latest version. Still, the error is same.

What I expect is the import statement for png/svg should work fine with both next js Image tag or normal HTML img tag.